# How do I set a Maven dependency version programmatically?

Tags: maven

Let's take this example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I know want to set `<version>` to be something of my choosing.

Something like
`mvn dependency:set-version <groupId>:<artifactId> <version-number>`

Specifically for slf4j, I might want:
`mvn dependency:set-version org.slf4j:slf4j-api 1.7.24`

I know I can use various auto-update methods/plugins to "bump" the version, but I don't want that. I want to set a specific version. The command should be flexible enough to accept *anything* as a version, or at least it should accept versions that can't currently be retrieved by Maven.

Note that I also want to avoid extracting the dependency version into a property that I set by other means.

I'm not looking for any solutions that involve the usage of the parent POM, or anything like that.

*Simply stated, the solution should be a `mvn` specific command that would replace, say, an invoication of `sed` to simply force the dependency version.*

Comment: Take a look at [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use the [following command](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-dep-version-mojo.html):

```
mvn versions:use-dep-version -Dincludes=junit:junit -DdepVersion=1.0 -DforceVersion=true
```

In includes is given like this: `groupId:artifactId` but can be something like this (quote from the docs):

> A list of artifact patterns to include. Follows the pattern
>   "groupId:artifactId:type:classifier:version".

The issue related to that is that via `forceVersion` any check which will be turned off to validate the version you have given to the versions which is available for the artifact so use it with care.