# Maven pom.xml - Automatically set dependency version from a file

Tags: maven

I'm working with a specific environment in which the version of a maven dependency is kept on a file.

e.g.

```
$ cat version_of_dependency
1.2.3
```

What I wanted to do is make the project `pom.xml` automatically read the file and fill the dependency, everytime its build lifecycle is triggered (for example, a simple `mvn clean install`).

Ideally, I wanted something like:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>my_dependency_gid</groupId>
      <artifactId>my_dependency_artifact</artifactId>
      <version>$(cat version_of_dependency)</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to do something like this? One option would be to have a properties file, but I wanted to keep the format of the version file untouched. Also, we wanted to avoid running a shell script before compiling.

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest if you don't use the pom to define the versions and the dependencies itself there is something wrong in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best you can get is to run a maven goal before to set the version (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913512/927493).

External files (may it be property files or not) cannot be used to define versions inside a POM. So you need to update the POM before you build.