# How do I dynamically read version from pom and update version for pom?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a spring boot application. I have a CICD pipeline that helps to deploy my application to QA env.

So my problem is this. My application requires a jar file that is generated during my pipeline. 
I would want to be able to get that jar file based on version number and used it in my app.

I have this idea of getting gitlab to update my pom version of the library that i am using to the version number ( it would usually be in sync with this app version number) and then get my application to read the version number.

Is this possible?

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code) for retrieving version number but i am unsure how to dynamically update the pom.xml version

Comment: I'm unsure what you real problem is: simply I would say add the dependency with version to your pom file?

Comment: My version changes with every build on the same project

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linked question to retrieve the version.

Then you can use the versions maven plugin to update the dependency version:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913512/927493